# updating specific columns in 2 table with different database

Tags: oracle

I have 2 DATABASEs WITH THE SAME table : *mytable*
 with column name_code and name

schema1@databse1

```
name_code | name
pf0tt.....|fact
gf09to3...|fact1
it031.....|papp
pf0tt.....|fattt
gf09to3...|fappt1
iy031.....|foot2
pf0tt.....|oooct
gf09to3...|ooct1
ru031.....|uuut2
pf0at.....|tttt
kk0eto3...|fact1
ll011.....|fact2
```

my problem is I have a table that has 500+ records (this one is an example) what I want is to select specific name in this table to insert them in the other table in the other database (`schema2@databse2`). How to do that in a query? I can do that by `select (update mytable set name_code = ..`

---

I'll explain more about my problem

I have about 300 name_code how can I insert them inside in( , ) ? and probably I would have 1000 name_code and function in ( , ) you can only insert 500 records only. How can the name_code in the above table put in the in  in ( , ) ?

Comment: 'insert' or 'update'? In SQL server you can just do 'FROM database.schema.table'

Comment: @NLwino INSERTS AND HOW TO SPECIFY 200 RECORDS ?IN('A','B','C'... ?)

Comment: We all understand that you have a long list of names but this fact alone won't help us to help you. In order to get helped you need to explain what rules can be applied to target those names that you need (e.g. all names that starts with 'fact' and all that end on '2' etc).

Comment: @peterm there is no rules , nothing is specifique, I am trying my best to explain my problem.
 I have a table with random name_code ( fb13,ity2,aklo0) in the real case they are about 300-400. those name_code has column called names (peterm, Moudiz, ben ).. the problem that in my other databse (not schema) the name_code exists but some of the name column are missing OR WRONG so i want to update the missing and with wrong names. how can i do that if i have large ammout of records?.Now is clearer right ?

Comment: A little bit clearer. Insert records that don't exist in the target table is fairly easy. See updated answer for an example. But to be able to fix (update) wrong records (as you stated) you need to define what exactly does that mean.

Comment: the column name has names (xkasd, ksadjs , qwoawejdas) and name_code(gh321,pot82,kl901) in the first server(not schema) in the second server(not schema) (peterm,Moudiz, Ben) and name_code(gh321,pot82,kl901) I wnat to replace the correct name in the 2nd server to the first server ( by server i mean : stack@flow , stack is the scheam and flow is the server, i am working on server levels)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
INSERT INTO schema2.mytable
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE name IN ('fact', 'fact1', ...)
       -- you can apply other conditions to narrow or broaden the results 
       -- of filtering source rows
```

*Assumption is that you execute this query from schema1*

Make sure that you have proper rights assigned in schema2 to be able to insert records.

**UPDATE** To insert all pairs (name_code, name) from schema1.mytable that not yet exist in schema2.mytable you can use a query like this

```
INSERT INTO schema2.mytable (name_code, name)
SELECT name_code, name
  FROM mytable1 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM schema2.mytable 
   WHERE name_code = t.name_code
     AND name = t.name
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24336/1)** demo

*Tweak conditions to serve your purpose*

You can also look into **[`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)** statement if you want to try to do that in one go (conditionally insert, update, delete).

Comment: perterm my problem here I have about 300 name_code how can I insert them inside in( , ) ? and propably I would have 1000 name_code and in ( , ) support specifque numbers

Comment: You either specify them all one by one comma separated in `IN()` or you can use pattern matching `LIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE` to target sets of names (e.g. all that starts with 'fact' and all that 'ooo' etc)